# How to query members of interest list via Open Graph?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I´ve just created my first public interest list "Matkailu" via facebook.com/addlist. Now I´m wondering how I´m able to query the list members via OG? Facebook seems to treat those new lists also as friendlists but method /members doesn´t seems to work.

My list id is 10150598089807055 and https://graph.facebook.com/10150598089807055 gives me this

```
{
"id": "10150598089807055",
"name": "Matkailu", 
"list_type": "user_created",
"type": "friendlist"
}
```

But if I try to query its members (which are mostly pages) like this https://graph.facebook.com/10150598089807055/members the result is empty.

So how can I get the members of those interest lists? Does the friendlists members connection give only people not pages as a result?

Comment: I'd appreciate an answer to this as well.